# no matches found: tensorflow[and-cuda]

Tags: python, pip, zsh

I am trying to install TensorFlow on my WSL on my laptop. The general installation of `pip install tensorflow` its successful. But it does detect GPU on my laptop. When I test GPU on it `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"` it does not detect any GPU even though I do have CUDA installed on the machine.

```
2024-03-09 10:15:18.941101: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

2024-03-09 10:15:19.496900: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-03-09 10:15:20.199286: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:984] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-03-09 10:15:20.199478: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

So i tried following the documentation and tried to install `python3 -m pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]`, but i get

```
zsh: no matches found: tensorflow[and-cuda]
```

I do have CUDA installed here are some details with `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.10              Driver Version: 551.61         CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 ...    On  |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   58C    P8             11W /  150W |       0MiB /  16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

More details about the setup

```
Python 3.12.2
pip 24.0
conda 24.1.2
WSL 2
 fedoraremix :
  NAME="Fedora Remix for WSL"
  VERSION="38"
Microsoft Windows :Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.4046)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+zsh%3A+no+matches+found

Comment: `pip install "tensorflow[and-cuda]"`

Comment: Give the linked duplicate a try.  I have a feeling it's only going to fix part of the problem on WSL, and that additional effort will be needed, but perhaps not.  If you are still having issues after correcting that, open a new question. Thanks!

Comment: @phd , even though I followed the suggestion, Tensorflow in my system still can't detect GPU. The `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"` still shows the same output as above;   please help with it or at least tell me how I can reopen the question. Let me know if I have to update the question so that someone can help me.

Comment: Please don't edit the question (the title in your case) to be a completely different question. This question was about `pip` and `zsh`. If you want to ask a different question after fixing zsh-related problem — ask it separately, do not reopen this one. One small problem at a time.